# C - my function backfires

Tags: c

When I call this function it always returns false and stops the program. But I cant figure out why.

```
// checks to see if the second argument is a positive interger, 
// and that there is only one arg
    if (ArgCheck (argc, shift) == false)
   {
       printf("You may only input one non-negative argument.\n");
       return 1;
    }
    else
        return true;
```

The function `ArgCheck` is:

```
int ArgCheck (int a, int b)
{
  if (a > 2)
        {
        return false;
        }
  else if (b < 0)
        {
        return false;  
        }
  else
    return 0;  
}
```

Even when I enter in the proper arguments in the command line, it still returns false. I know its a noob problem but I appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Comment: um, `0 == false`. C is strictly typed.

Comment: Your one function returns `true` and `1` and your other `false` and `0` - please stick to returning the same 'type's in the same function (i.e. return only `true` or `false` in the same function, don't mix `0` and `1` in there, and vice versa). Also, isn't `true` = `1` and `false` = `0` (usually?), so your functions return the same in all cases?.

Comment: you have ``true`` and ``false`` in C?

Comment: @gongzhitaao You're late by 14 years :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int ArgCheck (int a, int b)
{
  if (a > 2)
        {
        return false;
        }
  else if (b < 0)
        {
        return false;  
        }
  else
    return 0;  
}
```

This function returns false at all times.  `0` is the same as `false`.  Your requirement is:

> return true if the second argument is a positive integer and that there is only one arg

So...

```
bool ArgCheck(int argCount, int value)
{
    return argCount == 1 && value >= 0;
}
```

Note that I do not allow an argument count of 0 because you say that one argument is required.  Your current code allows no args.